# `cronnext` reports `nextstring` for every-minute cronjob as beginning of the *current* minute, ie in the *past*. Normal?

Tags: cron, anacron

So I'm seeing this weird thing  (or at least, weird to me, with my tiny amount of experience).

`cronnext` tells me the `nextstring` for an every-minute cronjob is the *beginning* of the *current* minute,
ie in the *past*.

eg, if I run `cronnext` at `02:11:27`,
it says:
`nextstring: Tue Jul 25 02:11:00 2023`
(
rather than (as I'd naively expect):
`nextstring: Tue Jul 25 02:12:00 2023`
)

Is this normal, or...?

Cuz I couldn't find anything about it in any of the manpages,
and I haven't been able to google anything up with the terms that I've been able to think of...

I added the `anacron` tag too,
cuz I *do* have it installed,
although I never used it directly,
so I don't know if it's relevant.

(
$`sudo cronnext -c`
#=>

```
  - user: "username"  
    crontab: /var/spool/cron/tabs/username  
    system: 0  
    entries:  
      - user: username  
        cmd: "/home/username/my_script.sh"  
        flags: 0x0F  
        flagnames: MIN_STAR|HR_STAR|DOM_STAR|DOW_STAR  
        delay: 0  
        next: 1690276260  
        nextstring: Tue Jul 25 02:11:00 2023  
next: 1690276260
```

)

(
I've already tracked down and fixed the bug I was originally trying to fix when I came across this,
so it turned out to just be a red-herring on that particular issue,
but I decided I still want to ask about it, cuz it still seems *weird* to me.
)

Comment: What distribution (and version) are you running?

Comment: @roaima Oh, sorry, I guess I was subconsciously expecting the answer to just be like "yeah, that's standard behavior didn't you know?" so it wouldn't matter, but
{$`cron -V`#=>`cronie 1.6.1`} (`openSUSE Tumbleweed 20230724`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool doesn't exist on Debian so I downloaded the latest version, [cronie-1.6.1](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/releases) from its source repository on Github.

The manpage writes in the *DESCRIPTION*,

> Determine the time `cron` will execute the next job. Without arguments, it prints  that time  considering all crontabs, in number of seconds since the Epoch, **rounded to the minute**.

(My emphasis.) It appears that the code always rounds down, which generates incorrect answers such as that which you've found.

Here's how I built it:

```
./configure --prefix=
make
```

And to run it:

```
src/cronnext
```

A fix appears to be to change the loop starting condition on line 250 of `src/cronnext.c` that calls `nextmatch()` to use `start+60` rather than `start`. However, I'm not confident enough of this to submit a patch, and I suspect that fixing `start` by adding 60 (seconds) where it's defined on line 344 rather than when it's used would be better.

Since you use the program, it would be best if you were to submit a bug report on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/issues).

Comment: Thanks! Done: https://github.com/cronie-crond/cronie/issues/150

Comment: @dwawlyn looks like you've got a fix already!